# Dynamic css in vue-loader component not working

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, vue-loader

I have a Vue Component and I would like to extend it in order to bind a color to a specific message. I tried it with a binding like

```
:style="styles"
```

but then I got the error

> Property or method "styles" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

or by making specific color classes in the css.

```
color--1
```

Got an error like

"Cannot read property '2' of undefined"

How can I bind the color of the class dynamically, by receiving a number from the API?

Here is my Code

```
<template>
    <div class="chat__message shadow" :class="{'chat__message--own': message.selfOwned, colorClass}" >

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import moment from 'moment'
    export default {
        props: ['message'],
        data(){
            return{
                time: '',
                colorArray: ['hsl(210 , 82 , 50 )', 'hsl(130 , 50 , 51 )', 'hsl(337 , 50 , 46 )','hsl(133 , 50 , 65 )', 'hsl(28 , 50 , 70 )','hsl(180 , 50 , 59 )' , 'hsl(274 , 50 , 82 )'],
                colorClass:'',
                styles: {
                    'background-color' : this.colorArray[2]
                },
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.time = moment(this.message.created_at).format('HH:mm');
            this.setColorClass(this.message.matchPosition);
        },
        methods: {
            setColorClass(number){
                this.colorClass = "color--" + number ;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    .color{
            &--1{background-color: hsl(210 , 82 , 50 );}
            &--2{background-color: hsl(130 , 50 , 51 );}
            &--3{background-color: hsl(337 , 50 , 46 );}
            &--4{background-color: hsl(133 , 50 , 65 );}
            &--5{background-color: hsl(28 , 50 , 70 );}
            &--6{background-color: hsl(180 , 50 , 59 );}
            &--7{background-color: hsl(274 , 50 , 82 );}
    }
    .chat{
        &__message{

            &--own{
                background-color: hsl(201, 100%, 55%);
                color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
                text-align: right;
}}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
export default {
     props: ['message'],
     data(){
         var self = this; // Add this
         return{
             time: '',
             colorArray: ['hsl(210 , 82 , 50 )', 'hsl(130 , 50 , 51 )', 'hsl(337 , 50 , 46 )','hsl(133 , 50 , 65 )', 'hsl(28 , 50 , 70 )','hsl(180 , 50 , 59 )' , 'hsl(274 , 50 , 82 )'],
             colorClass:'',
             styles: {
                 'background-color' : self.colorArray[2] // change here
             },
         }
     },
...
```

Comment: no still the same problem, with same errors... `Property or method "styles" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Comment: That `styles` should be a computed property imo. How do you intend to change it / what is its purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

The snippest you posted has no html which references `styles`, is another component trying to reference this component's `styles` variable?

> How can I bind the color of the class dynamically, by receiving a
>   number from the API?

If you add `cssEl` to your component's `data` object you can do something like this:

```
watch: {
  // Keep track of the color (or colors) taken from the api
  colorTakenFromApi () {
    // Remove the old class if it exists;
    this.cssEl && this.cssEl.remove();
    // Create the element in the DOM, then tell the browser it's a stylesheet
    this.cssEl = document.createElement('style');
    this.cssEl.type = 'text/css';
    // Use a text template to insert the css rule you want
    this.cssEl.innerHTML = `
      .${this.cssClass} {
        background-color: `${this.colorTakenFromApi}`
      }
    `;
  }
}
```

I think it's a bit of a hack, but this is what I used to change my css classes at runtime

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can't access `this` during initialization of data.

Work around would be:

Initialize your styles object as empty.

```
data(){
    return{
        time: '',
        colorArray: ['hsl(210 , 82 , 50 )', 'hsl(130 , 50 , 51 )', 'hsl(337 , 50 , 46 )','hsl(133 , 50 , 65 )', 'hsl(28 , 50 , 70 )','hsl(180 , 50 , 59 )' , 'hsl(274 , 50 , 82 )'],
        colorClass:'',
        styles: {},
    }
},
```

Then during `created` life-cycle set the initial style:

```
created() {
    this.time = moment(this.message.created_at).format('HH:mm');
    this.setColorClass(this.message.matchPosition);

    // Using Vue.set
    Vue.set(this, 'styles', {
        'background-color' : self.colorArray[2]
    });

    // OR Normal setting
    this.styles = {
        'background-color' : this.colorArray[2]
    };
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understands your problem but you can try computed methods:

```
props: ['message', 'colorNumber'],
computed: {
   getColorClass () {
      return 'color--' + this.colorNumber
   }
},
```

and in your template :

```
<template>
    <div :class="{'chat__message shadow': true,
                  'chat__message--own': message.selfOwned,
                   getColorClass: true}" >
    </div>
</template>
```

If you want to keep props as before and prop "message" is gonna change, you should use watch(deep kind) instead of computed one.

Otherwise if message props is not gonna change after page loaded then you can load it on data() variables and use it in computed method:

```
data(){
    return {
        colorNumber: '',
    }
},
mounted() {
   this.$nextTick(function () {
       // Code that will run only after the
       // entire view has been rendered

       this.colorNumber = this.message.matchPosition;
   })
},
```